# Do windows have a downside?

Tags: theme-hospital

Windows are supposed to make the staff happier. Placing them does not cost anything. Is there any reason not to fill the entire walls of every room with them?

Comment: Don't take this he wrong way but, I was mislead XD. I thought it was for windows OS.

Answer (score 4):

The only downside I can see is the extra bit of time it takes to place them but I guess that it's time well spent.
Furthermore according to this [strategy wiki](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Theme_Hospital/Rooms#Doors_and_windows) adding windows should also make it easier to place and edit furniture in the room.

Comment: " Furthermore according to this strategy wiki adding windows should also make it easier to place and edit furniture in the room." -- I think that's just because it makes the interior of the room easier to see for the player.

Comment: Yes that is probably correct. Couldn't really think of any other reason myself but it has been a while since I played Theme Hospital (which will probably change in a few hours thanks to your question)